# RegOpenKeyEx for SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SeCEdit\Reg Values returns Error Code 2

Tags: c++, windows, registry, gpo

I am using IGroupPolicyObject Interface to open a registry key. I loaded the Registry using GPO_SECTION_MACHINE but, when I open the registry key "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SeCEdit\Reg Values" using RegOpenKeyEx, an error code of 2 is returned. I am running my exe (built in Visual Studio 2008, c++) as Administrator. I would like to know how to open the above mentioned key ?Any form of help would be highly appreciated.

Below is the code I am using to open the key.

```
GUID RegistryId = REGISTRY_EXTENSION_GUID;
GUID ThisAdminToolGuid =
{
    0x0F6B957E,
    0x509E,
    0x11D1,
    {0xA7, 0xCC, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF8, 0x75, 0x71, 0xE3}
};

hres = CoCreateInstance(
                    CLSID_GroupPolicyObject,
                    NULL,
                    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                    IID_IGroupPolicyObject,
                    (LPVOID*)&pIGroupPolicyObject
                    );
if (S_OK != hres || NULL == pIGroupPolicyObject)
{
    _tprintf(_T("\n hres != S_OK"));
    return FALSE;
}

hres = pIGroupPolicyObject->OpenLocalMachineGPO(GPO_OPEN_LOAD_REGISTRY);
if (FAILED(hres))
{

    _tprintf(_T("\n hres != S_OK"));
    return FALSE;
}

hres = pIGroupPolicyObject->GetRegistryKey(GPO_SECTION_MACHINE, &hGPOSectionUserKey);
if (FAILED(hres) || NULL == hGPOSectionUserKey)
{

    _tprintf(_T("\n hres != S_OK"));
    return FALSE;
}
lRetVal = RegOpenKeyEx(hGPOSectionUserKey, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\SeCEdit\\Reg Values\\MACHINE/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/LanManServer/Parameters/NullSessionShares"), 0, KEY_READ, &hSettingUserKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `RegOpenKeyEx` returns 2 which is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. That means that the path that you supply does not exist. Which is correct. You supplied: `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\SeCEdit\\Reg Values\\MACHINE/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/LanManServer/Parameters/NullSessionShares"`.

For sure that path does not exist. You should instead pass: `"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\SeCEdit\\Reg Values"`.

Comment: As per your suggestion, if I only use the latter mentioned path, RegOpenKeyEx still returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: Well, that tells you that the file does not exist. Perhaps the registry redirector is burning you.,

Comment: I am running my application on a 32 bit virtual machine so I dont think that I have been a victim of registry redirection.

Comment: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND is pretty unequivocal